# Why does document.getElementById Return null here?

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't the following piece of code work?  I'm trying to write an application that will generate a certain number of divs based on user input.  When I go into the console on this application, and put in the line that says: `var i = document.getElementById("foo");`  It returns as null.

```
<div>
    <input type="number" id="foo" value="3"/>
</div>

<div>
    <script>
        var i = document.getElementById("foo");
        for (var num = 1; num <= i; num++) {
            document.write('<div id="' + i + '"> ... </div>');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Uhm, I'd say it's because document.write overwrites the document ?

Comment: And you're not getting the value, but the element

Comment: Also, note that your `i` is an HTML element. `num` is a number. Ask yourself how exactly JS is supposed to interpret your `if (element smaller than number)` conditional?

Comment: @adeneo document.write will only overwrite the document if it's called after the DOM is finalised, so in this case document.write is "safe", but still something alex0112 should not be using.

Comment: `if (Banana > 293) { doThis() }`

Comment: @KevinB - It's `Banana`, only one `n`

Comment: define exactly what property of the "i" element you want by adding .value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the comments under the questions !

Also, creating proper elements is usually a good thing.

```
<div>
    <input type="number" id="foo" value="3"/>
</div>

<div>
    <script>
        var i = document.getElementById("foo").value;
        for (var num = 1; num <= i; num++) {
            var elem = document.createElement('div');
            elem.id  = 'elem' + num;
            elem.innerHTML = ' ... ';
            document.body.appendChild(elem)
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aLgx6/2/)

Comment: But if OP says `document.getElementById("foo")` returns `null`, then `document.getElementById("foo").value` will throw an error.

Comment: @Oriol - Probably, but then the OP's browser isn't working, so it doesn't matter what he does !

Comment: @adeneo.  Looks like it's working fine. Missing semicolon on the last line of the function.  But other than that fine.  I'm running one more test though.

Comment: little error here : elem.id = 'elem' + num; and not i as var , else every elements has same id :)  http://jsfiddle.net/aLgx6/3/